# mapView not zooming on second try using didUpdateUserLocation

Tags: ios, mkmapview, android-mapview

i am loading a mapviewcontroller when the view map button is pressed from my mainviewcontroller:

```
- (IBAction)mapButton:(id)sender {
    MapKitDisplayViewController *mapKitDisplayView = [[MapKitDisplayViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:mapKitDisplayView animated:YES];   
    [mapKitDisplayView release]; mapKitDisplayView = nil;
}
```

On startup of this map view this method is called, which correctly zooms to the users location:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation 
{ 
    myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    NSLog(@"didUpdateUserLocation = '%@'", userLocation);

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([userLocation coordinate], 20000, 20000);
    [myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

I have a done button on this screen that dismisses this view:

```
- (IBAction)mapDoneButton:(id)sender 
{    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

At this stage the user is taken back to the main view controller, however when i press the view map button again, the didUpdateUserLocation method is never called! Hence, the map view is zoomed out to the default one and wont zoom in as before.

How can i get it to be called again?

thanks

Comment: Where are all your `showsUserLocation` calls put? and what values are they set to?

Comment: sorry ignore showUserLocation - that was just me testing stuff out. This finds and zooms to user: MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([userLocation coordinate], 20000, 20000);
    [myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];   At the moment I am just using the default user location that is found by the gps. I also only have the simulator to test on right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MKMapView` object doesn't trigger an update on user location on its own. You need to activate the search by setting `showsUserLocation = YES`. This will then fetch the user's location and then the delegate method `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` is called. So set this value to `YES` on `viewWillAppear:` and once you've the user location you can set it to `NO` to stop tracking the user. If you don't do that, it periodically updates the user location and calls the delegate method. Without doing this, user location should be unreliable.

Comment: this still didnt work :( is it because im using the simulator? Doing this did exactly the same thing! The viewWillAppear is called everytime, but the mapView:didUpdateUserLocation: still doesnt register on the second try the uiviewcontroller is created.

Comment: Just to make it clearer, i can get the users location fine and the blue point is showing correctly too, this even works fine when I go out of the mapview and go back in again. Its just that the zoom is not working on the second time im loading the mapviewcontroller for the mapview!

Comment: I made a test application which you can [`download`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/MapCenter.zip). It seems to be working fine.

Comment: thanks alot Deepak, wow you are amazingly fast! Really appreciate your help. Guess what it turned out to be? The code was all right, but the problem was in interface builder on my MKMAPVIEW I had the showUserLocation box ticked!! :( Cant believe how much grief that caused me, but thanks to your test app I was able to find it :D

Comment: @GameDev Loads of thanks mate! You saved my day..This was the same issue for me.. It was resolved when I unticked the showsUserLocation property in NIB.

Comment: @GameDev I had the showUserLocation box clicked as well and come up with the same problem as yours, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What i do is next:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"gotUserLocation" object:self];}
```

then in viewDidLoad check of user location is available. if it is not register view controller as reciever for that notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(zoomToLocation) name:@"gotUserLocation" object:nil];
```

if user location is available just call zoomToLocation method

Comment: hi mate, tried this aswell - but again works fine on first load of the view, but on second load even though this line runs: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(zoomToLocation) name:@"gotUserLocation" object:nil]; The other methods do not trigger at all: zoomToLocation or even didUpdateUserLocation!